# EditorFor with Nested Property when property is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I have a `PersonVm` that has a nested `Street2` view model. In my person view I have an custom editor template for `Street2` based on the `PersonType` property, but when the `Street2` property is null it returns unformatted text boxes instead of no template. Is there a way to tell the MVC framework if the `Street2` property is null do not try and render a template. Right now I am doing an `IF` statement in the view. (this is an oversimplified example). Thanks.

**Person View Model**

```
public class PersonVm
{
    public string PersonType { get; set; }
    public Street2 Street2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Person View**

```
 @model App.Models.PersonVm

    @*... other controls *@
    @* Right Now i am doing this if logic*@

    @if(Model.Street2 != null)
    {
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Street2, person.PersonType)
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why would you want to hide the editor for `Street2` if `Street2` has no value set. How would you ever get a value into it in the first place?

Comment: We have expected records for persons and they can only edit `Street2` if we have that original record. Does that help?